# Image layed over a table - HTML mail

Tags: html, css, html-table, html-email

I'm looking for a possible way to get a image overlay some tables. I tried Z-positioning but it didn't. Maybe I didn't do it right. I hope someone can give me some tips to get me in the right direction.

Reminder: 
**I can't use div, because its a HTML mail.**

*CodeSample:*

```
<table width="100%" align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td align="left" bgcolor="ffffff" width="69%" class="bodycopy shadow" style="padding: 10px;">
            <p class="h1">Lorem Titel            </p>
            <p class="h2">Lorem subtitle
            </p>
            <p class="bodycopy">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam dictum eleifend purus, eu lobortis odio viverra ac. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Maecenas non lobortis purus, et convallis dolor. In euismod felis sed ex consequat, non suscipit magna laoreet. Etiam non libero consequat erat interdum sollicitudin nec ut est. Nam quis nisl mi. Nulla lobortis justo nulla, ac vestibulum mauris dictum nec.
                <br />
                <br />Lorem ipsum.
                <br />dolar sit amet
            </p>
            <a href="#" </a>
        </td>
        <td width="2%">
            <img style="top: 0; z-index: 2; border: 1px solid #f00;" src="Fotos/icon-vb.gif">
        </td>
        <td align="right" class="shadow" width="29%">
            <img class="fix" src="ipod.gif" width="100%" border="0" alt="" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Just giving it a z-index is not going to work, as it needs a position too. And since it's an HTML email, positioning using `position:absolute` is not going to work on a vast majority of email clients unfortunately.

Comment: I will keep that in mind and run some tests!

Comment: Even though support for ```position``` seems strong, these major clients do not support it: Outlook, Gmail, and Android. Unless you are certain most of your recipients aren't viewing their emails in any of these clients, it's not a good idea to implement this because it will appear to be extremely broken without full support for ```position```. [CSS Support in Email](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make following changes in html and CSS. Add `z-index: 999;position:absolute;` to small image and `position:relative;`   to other

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8fu1354t/1/)**

**HTML**

```
 <img class='smallimg' src="Fotos/icon-vb.gif">
```

**CSS**

```
  .smallimg {
    z-index: 999;
    position:absolute;
    border: 1px solid #f00
}
.fix {
    position:relative;
}
```

Comment: This really sends me in the right direction, I'm wondering why you have z-index: 999? Also its now overlapping the right side, i guess i can try the same with so it also doing the same on the left?

Comment: You can even use z-index:1;. And yes you can do same for left side :)